# Difficulty Understanding Recursion on C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this example block of code that I tried to replicate, a recursive function for finding Fibonacci numbers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n)
{
if (n==0)
 return 0;
else if (n==1)
 return 1;
else return fibonacci(n-1)+(n-2);
}

int main()
{
cout<<fibonacci(15);
}
```

the following example outputs

```
92
```

when executed.

Looking at some examples now, I see that the formula is wrong, but I am still curious as to why the output is what it is, as I have been having a hard time trying to understand how recursion works.

Comment: Tip: draw a recursion tree on a piece of paper to find out how it works.

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through the code, it will help you understand how recursion works pretty quickly. So would putting a `cout<<n` at the beginning of your `fibonacci()` function.

Comment: 1) What's unclear about recursion? `fibonacci(n-1)+(n-2);` is equivalent to `fibonacci(n-1) + n - 2;` So, it's basically equal to `15 + 14 + 13 + 12 + 11 + 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 - 2 * 14`, or in more general terms: `sum (n) - 2 * (n - 1)` What's unclear about that?

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn about how the stack works.

Answer (score 1):

You should be adding the previous two fibonacci numbers, so `fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)`, not `fibonacci(n - 1) + (n - 2)`, which lacks a function call. With `fibonacci(n - 1) + (n - 2)`, you simply add `n - 2` to the previous term in the series, giving you a series similar to triangular numbers.

Comment: Should probably be noted that this has exponential time complexity, and is one of the most computationally expensive ways to actually calculate Fibonacci numbers.  Something as simple as `fibonacci(42)` results in just shy of one billion recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other user posted, you're missing the function call for the `(n-2)` portion.

As far as how recursion works, think of it like a [tree](https://miro.medium.com/max/1488/1*uc4P0Yg_2vvusGEdsxVLBg.png). For each function call, your current state on the stack is saved, and you move your program counter to the function call; it just so happens to be that it's also the current function you are in. When you get to the bottom of the tree, you'll unwind the stack.

This returns the correct answer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n)
{
if (n==0)
    return 0;
else if (n==1)
    return 1;
else 
    return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<fibonacci(15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n)
{
  if (n==0) //base case
    return 0;
  else if (n==1) //base case
    return 1;
  else return fibonacci(n-1)+ fibonacci(n-2);
}

int main()
{
    cout<<fibonacci(15);
}
```

When you first call the fibonacci function, `fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)` means `fibonacci(14) + fibonacci(13)`. The recursion happens, the next pass will be `fibonacci(13) + fibonacci(12)` and `fibonacci(12) + fibonacci(11)` respectively. The recursion processes will continue with this manner until it hits one of the base cases, the recursion will then stop and start to return values.